# Attach session numbers to its relevant IDs

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

I have long records were collected as an output of a code,

```
Part1=STS768976N-4BT345432-X00001-87675789AAAS Session=9
Part2=STS876578N-2BT234522-X00002-23456789UJHG Session=10
Part3=ST9876887N-1BT876577-X00003-65778978KJUH Session=11
Session=10 70000
Session=11 80000
Session=9 90000
```

I want to organize the data like this

```
Part1=STS768976N-4BT345432-X00001-87675789AAAS 90000
Part2=STS876578N-2BT234522-X00002-23456789UJHG 70000
Part3=ST9876887N-1BT876577-X00003-65778978KJUH 80000
```

how can i do that

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can do it:

```
awk '/Part/{i[$2]=$1;next}$1 in i{print i[$1],$2}' file | sort -t= -k1

Part1=STS768976N-4BT345432-X00001-87675789AAAS 90000
Part2=STS876578N-2BT234522-X00002-23456789UJHG 70000
Part3=ST9876887N-1BT876577-X00003-65778978KJUH 80000
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach takes 2 passes over the file: once to collect the ids, then again to print the results

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {if (/^Session=/) id[$1] = $2; next} 
    /^Part/ {$NF = id[$NF]; print}
' file file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in Session=9 Session=10 Session=11; do sed -n '/'$i'/p' j.txt| sed "N;s/\n/ /g"| sed 's/'$i'//g'; done
Part1=STS768976N-4BT345432-X00001-87675789AAAS   90000
Part2=STS876578N-2BT234522-X00002-23456789UJHG   70000
Part3=ST9876887N-1BT876577-X00003-65778978KJUH   80000
```